# group by 'last' value in bash

Tags: bash

I have a two-column file:

```
1,112
1,123
2,123
2,124
2,144
3,158
4,123
4,158
5,123
```

I need to know last column2 value for each column1:

```
1,123
2,144
3,158
4,158
5,123
```

how to do this in `bash` ?

Comment: input file is always sorted so?

Comment: @Sundeep yes it's sorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of solutions:

1) With `tac` to reverse input file and `sort`

```
$ tac ip.txt | sort -u -t, -k1,1n
1,123
2,144
3,158
4,158
5,123
```

2) With `perl`

```
$ perl -F, -ne '$h{$F[0]} = $_; END{print $h{$_} foreach (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %h)}' ip.txt 
1,123
2,144
3,158
4,158
5,123
```

Input lines split on `,` and hash variable keeps updating based on first field, effectively throwing away previous lines if first field matches. At end, the hash variable is printed based on sorted keys

Thanks @choroba for pointing out that numeric sort is needed in both cases

Comment: As the 1st column contains numbers, numeric sort might be needed both in bash `-k1,1n` and Perl `sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk delimit on `,` to store each `$2` in an array using key as `$1`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {seen[$1]=$2} END{for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]}' file.csv

1,123
2,144
3,158
4,158
5,123
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty similar to @Sundeep's solution but here it goes:

```
$ tac file|uniq -w 1|tac
1,123
2,144
3,158
4,158
5,123
```

ie. reverse the record order with `cat`, `uniq` outputs based on the first character only and then the order is reversed again.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash:

```
declare -A array   # associative array

# read from file
while IFS=, read a b; do array[$a]="$b"; done < file

# print array
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "$i,${array[$i]}"; done
```

Output:

```
1,123
2,144
3,158
4,158
5,123
```